# Fetch Total Cost of Today Orders

Tags: views, 7, hooks

I am using Drupal-6 . i am using ubbercart module here. In Content type Product I have a field named Actual Amount.

Now i want to get total of Actual Amount by Datawise only .

Can Anybody tell me how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views could do this and you might also want to use [views calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc), setup a view to display all orders with a filter to show only last day, then add the field for amount and use views calc to sum the total.